# java servlet Invoking javascript pop-up / modal dialog in web page from external event

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, modal-dialog, popup

I have a java servlet application running under Apache Tomcat which displays web pages. The application also includes a TCP listener. When a TCP packet is received from another process, I need to alert the user, preferably by means of a popup / modal dialog. However, I am unable to find guidance on how the external event (receipt of the TCP packet) is supposed to alert the web page to display the popup. All the Javascript examples I have seen rely on the user clicking a button or something similar.

(I have tried creating an XMLHttpRequest object in the web page and using that to fire a dummy HTTP request to the servlet application when the page loads. The application would start a Thread which would not return anything to the request (and thereby change the XMLHttpRequest obect's state) until the TCP packet is received. However, this object either returns a changed state of 4 "(request finished, response ready") instantly or fails to send the HTTP request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Keyword: websocket.